# How to reset the Master Password without current password on OS X?

Tags: macos, filevault

This is **not** the user or admin login password. Running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

To set or change the Master Password first click on the gear (1) and a new dialog box will open (2)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a recovery key?

Answer (score 4):

The **Master Password** is more a safety net than a security measure.

Without any user password you may reset or delete the Master Password by booting to your Recovery HD, starting Terminal, mounting your main volume, navigating to /Library/Keychains and deleting the files FileVaultMaster.cer and FileVaultMaster.keychain.

If your main volume is encrypted you won't be able to mount it without a proper FileVault password.

Comment: Once the two files are deleted, will I be able to set a new Master PW. Also, will deleting the Keychain File have an effect on my other Apple devices i.e. Phones, ipads